# How to select all after URI segment 2 in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, url, uri

I encoded some data and sent it through url as `$this->uri->segment(2)` and encoded string contains '/' and other symbols. I can not select full URI segment because of those '/' signs. 
My main question is, how to select in controller everything after URI segment 1?

```
$enc_session_email = $this->encrypt->encode($this->session->userdata('email'));
```

and I get the url result:

```
http://localhost/ci/new-affilate/YWwfV9KJrOiY+J08WUcufZkmKbW5ST7wTp+bofnRP35bv/gzvA+5fYo7J6jDCvt0NwzMiEFdU2r3+a8+scqLTA==
```

How to get all after new-affilate in controller?

Comment: Alex, please show your code to us (the one which encodes things), then show us the unwanted outputs so we can take a better look at it.

Comment: You want everything after `$this->uri segment(2)` or after `$this->uri->segment(1)`? Wasn't `new-affiliate` actually `$this->uri->segment->(1)`?

Comment: Very sorry for bad problem describing. Yes new-affilate is segment(1) and I need all after that.

Comment: Ok. And it is actually `$this->uri->rsegment(1)` since it is routed segment, right?

Comment: well, `$this->uri->rsegment(1)` is goint to the next '/' symbol and I need everything else after  `$this->uri->segment(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be suficient:

```
$encoded_string = ltrim($this->uri->ruri_string(), $this->uri->slash_rsegment(1, 'trailing'));
```

Comment: I get all after `$this->uri->segment(1)` but also I am getting name of my function from controller.

Comment: Have you tried exact code I posted? What is `var_dump($encoded_string)` after that?

Comment: @AleksandarMilic I am not sure why this wouldn't work. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your URL like this:

```
http://localhost/ci/new-affilate?enc_session_email=$enc_session_email
```

and then get it like this:

```
$enc_session_email = $this->input->get('enc_session_email', TRUE);
```